# Blue Screens From Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, error-handling

Will a machine running Windows 7 that gets bluescreens get errors of any kind with a complete disk wipe and installation of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

It depends why you were getting blue screens for. If they were caused by a failing hard disk, then you will probably get similar problems with Ubuntu.

Check your disk for errors and if bad sectors show up, you need to consider forking out for a new HDD

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the error.

If it is an hardware fault then nothing can be done by a change of operating system.

It if an operating system problem, then moving to another OS (like Ubuntu) can solve the problem.